# Show App Open Ads only on'cold start ' - openigng app from device home screen app icon

Tags: android, callback, admob, android-lifecycle, cold-start

I have an app with Splash Screen and App Open Ads. Currently App Open Ads are showing **three ways**, when user -

**1st one:** *opening app clicking app icon* - [Like this:](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/RfEBUmG8zxMvx4WAuEpPsRTgAIunO0_vsK1-xH1pFgnR2OkSTDh6dtHI7GvtTwLW8gk=w895) App icon click > splash screen > showing App Open Ads (splash screen is behind) > close App Open Ads > showing progress (splash screen) > main activity

**2nd one:** *coming back to app from task manager.* - i.e: main activity or any other activity > left the app > coming back to app (from task manager) > App Open Ads (the activity is behind where user left before leaving app) > close App Open Ads > viewing that activity

**3rd one:** *coming back to app clicking app icon.* - i.e: main activity or any other activity > left the app > coming back to app (using app icon) > App Open Ads (the activity is behind where user left before leaving app) > close App Open Ads > viewing that activity

As second and third way violation admob policy, So I want to show App Open Ads **only using 1st way.** not the second and third way. How to achieve that?

My Code is: MyApplication.java

```
package com.google.android.gms.example.appopenexample;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.LoadAdError;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.appopen.AppOpenAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.appopen.AppOpenAd.AppOpenAdLoadCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import java.util.Date;

/** Application class that initializes, loads and show ads when activities change states. */
public class MyApplication extends Application
    implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, DefaultLifecycleObserver {

  private AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager;
  private Activity currentActivity;
  private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

    // Log the Mobile Ads SDK version.
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Mobile Ads SDK Version: " + MobileAds.getVersion());

    MobileAds.initialize(
        this,
        new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
          @Override
          public void onInitializationComplete(
              @NonNull InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    appOpenAdManager = new AppOpenAdManager();
  }

  /**
   * DefaultLifecycleObserver method that shows the app open ad when the app moves to foreground.
   */
  @Override
  public void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onStart(owner);
    // Show the ad (if available) when the app moves to foreground.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(currentActivity);
  }

  /** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods. */
  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // An ad activity is started when an ad is showing, which could be AdActivity class from Google
    // SDK or another activity class implemented by a third party mediation partner. Updating the
    // currentActivity only when an ad is not showing will ensure it is not an ad activity, but the
    // one that shows the ad.
    if (!appOpenAdManager.isShowingAd) {
      currentActivity = activity;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {}

  @Override
  public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

  /**
   * Shows an app open ad.
   *
   * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
   * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
   */
  public void showAdIfAvailable(
      @NonNull Activity activity,
      @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
    // We wrap the showAdIfAvailable to enforce that other classes only interact with MyApplication
    // class.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(activity, onShowAdCompleteListener);
  }

  /**
   * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an app open ad is complete
   * (i.e. dismissed or fails to show).
   */
  public interface OnShowAdCompleteListener {
    void onShowAdComplete();
  }

  /** Inner class that loads and shows app open ads. */
  private class AppOpenAdManager {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenAdManager";
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294";

    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private boolean isLoadingAd = false;
    private boolean isShowingAd = false;

    /** Keep track of the time an app open ad is loaded to ensure you don't show an expired ad. */
    private long loadTime = 0;

    /** Constructor. */
    public AppOpenAdManager() {}

    /**
     * Load an ad.
     *
     * @param context the context of the activity that loads the ad
     */
    private void loadAd(Context context) {
      // Do not load ad if there is an unused ad or one is already loading.
      if (isLoadingAd || isAdAvailable()) {
        return;
      }

      isLoadingAd = true;
      AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      AppOpenAd.load(
          context,
          AD_UNIT_ID,
          request,
          new AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
             *
             * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
             */
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
              appOpenAd = ad;
              isLoadingAd = false;
              loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded.");
              Toast.makeText(context, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            /**
             * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
             *
             * @param loadAdError the error.
             */
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
              isLoadingAd = false;
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + loadAdError.getMessage());
              Toast.makeText(context, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });
    }

    /** Check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
      long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - loadTime;
      long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
      return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }

    /** Check if ad exists and can be shown. */
    private boolean isAdAvailable() {
      // Ad references in the app open beta will time out after four hours, but this time limit
      // may change in future beta versions. For details, see:
      // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en
      return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
      showAdIfAvailable(
          activity,
          new OnShowAdCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowAdComplete() {
              // Empty because the user will go back to the activity that shows the ad.
            }
          });
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(
        @NonNull final Activity activity,
        @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
      // If the app open ad is already showing, do not show the ad again.
      if (isShowingAd) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is already showing.");
        return;
      }

      // If the app open ad is not available yet, invoke the callback then load the ad.
      if (!isAdAvailable()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is not ready yet.");
        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
        loadAd(activity);
        return;
      }

      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

      appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
          new FullScreenContentCallback() {
            /** Called when full screen content is dismissed. */
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
              // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
              appOpenAd = null;
              isShowingAd = false;

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.");
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
              loadAd(activity);
            }

            /** Called when fullscreen content failed to show. */
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
              appOpenAd = null;
              isShowingAd = false;

              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: " + adError.getMessage());
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();

              onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
              loadAd(activity);
            }

            /** Called when fullscreen content is shown. */
            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent.");
              Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });

      isShowingAd = true;
      appOpenAd.show(activity);
    }
  }
}
```

For SplashActivity:

```
package com.google.android.gms.example.appopenexample;    
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.example.appopenexample.MyApplication.OnShowAdCompleteListener;

/** Splash Activity that inflates splash activity xml. */
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String LOG_TAG = "SplashActivity";

  /**
   * Number of seconds to count down before showing the app open ad. This simulates the time needed
   * to load the app.
   */
  private static final long COUNTER_TIME = 5;

  private long secondsRemaining;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    // Create a timer so the SplashActivity will be displayed for a fixed amount of time.
    createTimer(COUNTER_TIME);
  }

  /**
   * Create the countdown timer, which counts down to zero and show the app open ad.
   *
   * @param seconds the number of seconds that the timer counts down from
   */
  private void createTimer(long seconds) {
    final TextView counterTextView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer =
        new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000, 1000) {
          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            secondsRemaining = ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) + 1);
            counterTextView.setText("App is done loading in: " + secondsRemaining);
          }

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {
            secondsRemaining = 0;
            counterTextView.setText("Done.");

            Application application = getApplication();

            // If the application is not an instance of MyApplication, log an error message and
            // start the MainActivity without showing the app open ad.
            if (!(application instanceof MyApplication)) {
              Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to cast application to MyApplication.");
              startMainActivity();
              return;
            }

            // Show the app open ad.
            ((MyApplication) application)
                .showAdIfAvailable(
                    SplashActivity.this,
                    new OnShowAdCompleteListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onShowAdComplete() {
                        startMainActivity();
                      }
                    });
          }
        };
    countDownTimer.start();
  }

  /** Start the MainActivity. */
  public void startMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

App open ad units should only appear when the user opens an app **or** switches back to an app, 1 or the other NEVER BOTH.

More info here:
[https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en#:~:text=App%20open%20ad%20units%20should,open%20ads%20on%20these%20screens](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en#:%7E:text=App%20open%20ad%20units%20should,open%20ads%20on%20these%20screens).

```
@Override
public void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onStart(owner);
    // Show the ad (if available) when the app moves to foreground.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(currentActivity);
}

**//This will stop the ad from showing when returning to the app**
@Override
public void onStop(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onStop(owner);
    owner.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
}
```